# Affine Spaces and Affine transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, affine-geometry

Can anyone please recommend a book that describes Affine Spaces and Affine Transformations? Many books i saw described it very briefly. Can anyone please suggest a book that deals with it in detail?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [Kaplansky's "Linear Algebra and Geometry", Chapter 3](http://books.google.com/books?id=nUcUYHrYJtgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=kaplansky+geometry&source=bl&ots=2TvukhIyXC&sig=MKWhzs8uyQuBm-YX_VPONia3x9k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QF5QUNDcMs6Qswa8w4GADQ&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=kaplansky%20geometry&f=false). It contains some stuff but you might want it more detailed.

Comment: There's a long list of books at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_geometry#References).

Answer (score 3):

For the more geometrical concepts related to affine spaces, a good resource is Chapter 2 of Marcel Berger's [*Geometry I*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387116583). (To get the most out of it, one should review Chapters 0 and 1 to make sure the concepts and terminologies used are familiar.)

Comment: Hi all, i saw the book(Geometry I by Marcel Berger) preview on Amazon. Could anyone please let me know if this would be too much for a newbie? I saw the contents and it seems very interesting. I am planning on buying this book.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by newbie `:-)` The publisher [lists the content level of the book at "lower undergraduate"](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-3-540-11658-5), and I remember the discussion being very intuitive (once you learn how to translate the notation into mental pictures) and down-to-earth, so shouldn't be too hard to get into. (BTW, Springer also sells eBook edition of this book at a slight discount, if you want to save money.)

Answer (score 3):

You can read Jean Gallier's book *Basics of Affine Geometry*, which is available from Springer.  Gallier also has some notes on this topic available for free download at
ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/papers/gallier/geomath2.pdf and at http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/geombchap2.pdf.